# Not able to repair this formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF($E8:$E12+$G8:$M11,"A")+(COUNTIF($E8:$E12+$G8:$M11,"AH")/2)=0,"",COUNTIF($E8:$E12+$G8:$M11,"A")+(COUNTIF($E8:$E12+$G8:$M11,"AH")/2))
```

I am selecting some cells in Excel and I am calculating value A,AH based on those cells

- A means 1
- AH means 0.5.

In theses cells $E8:$E12+$G8:$M11 I am caluclating  A AH values in these cells

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more, I understand that the formula has errors but I don't quite understand what you are trying to acheive

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply add ranges. $E8:$E12+$G8:$M11 causes an error.

If ranges F8:F12 and G12:M12 are empty and will always be empty you can simply use $E$8:$M$12 instead of $E8:$E12+$G8:$M11. If this is not possible I would simply use a sum of COUNTIF functions, one for range $E8:$E12 and one for range $G8:$M11.

Also you seem to have a problem of class =if(x=0,something,x) and x is always numeric. If x expression is lengthy, writing it twice might be difficult to read or play with. In such situations I sometimes use =iferror(1/(1/x),something). If x is zero then 1/x results in error, thus "something" is returned, if x is nonzero 1/(1/x) which is simply x is returned.